# Why won't my animation effect work?

Tags: jquery, jquery-effects

Beginer question:

i load ->

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

after that mt js file

all in the head section.

html:

```
<li class="form-row" id="req-shake">
  <label class="requried-field"> *</label>
  <label>some label</label>
  <input id="input-email" name="email" type="text" class="text-input required email default"  value="" title="example@example.com" />
</li>
```

js error:

[image: js error:]

am i doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Have you definitely loaded your mt.js file? Also, try putting the js code within a: $(document).ready(function() { ...  }); block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include these three files too

```
 <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i thought that 'jquery-ui.min.js' and 'jquery-ui.css' stands for things like datepicker and stuff not jquery functions

Comment: yeah you are right but effects function is of jquery ui not of default jquery

Answer (score 0):

As the error message in your console tells you, [there is no `.effect()` method of jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/effect).
You should include jQuery UI in addition to jQuery to get [the `.effect()` method from jQuery UI](http://api.jqueryui.com/effect/).